# Django: Image Field not showing up

Tags: django, imagefield

So my image is not displaying, here is my code:
models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class ProfileImage(models.Model):
    """
    Profile model
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        verbose_name=_('User'),
        to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='profile',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image')
```

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mifamiliaesundesastre/media')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from Home.views import home_view
from accounts.views import login_view, register_view, logout_view, user_home
from chat.views import Messages

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home_view, name='home'),
    path('login/', login_view),
    path('signup/', register_view),
    path('logout/', logout_view),
    path('home/', user_home),
    path('messages/', include('chat.urls')),
    path('messages/', Messages),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

user_home.html:

```
 <img src="{{ user.profileimage.avatar.url }}" alt="profile image">
```

I did all correct, also I can see my images in my media folders but in my template does not show up,
does anybody know what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sinc the `related_name='profile'` in the `ForeignKey` is `'profile'`, you access it with

```
<img src="{{ user.profile.avatar.url }}" alt="profile image">
```

The [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) is the name of the relation in *reverse*. So to obtain the related `ProfileImage` object from a `User` object.

You can also decide to change `related_name=…` to `related_name='profileimage'`, then you of course use `{{ user.profileimage.avatar.url }}`.